# continuous, monotonic increasing function with special property

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, ceiling-and-floor-functions, monotone-functions

Let $f$ be any continuous monotonically increasing function with property that

$f(x) \in\mathbb Z\Rightarrow x \in\mathbb Z$

In the related proof, it says,

if $\lfloor x \rfloor < x$
then
$f(\lfloor x \rfloor) < f(x)$

I believe the inequality should be 
$f(\lfloor x \rfloor) \le f(x)$
, since $f$ is not strictly increasing.

how we coclude that the function is strictly increasing?

Comment: It depends on your definition of "monotonically increasing." Some authors take "increasing" to mean what you might call "strictly increasing" and "nondecreasing" to mean what you might call "increasing."

Comment: author has not specified f as strictly increasing, only monotonically increasing function, I believe the special property provides some insight that it may be strictly increasing for non-integers/integers?

Comment: No, the "special property" doesn't strengthen the implications of the increasingness of $f$. Consider $f(x) = r$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ for some $r\in \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Z}$. Then $f$ has the property you're referring to, but $f$ is both increasing/nondecreasing and _not_ strictly increasing.

Comment: My conclusion is therefore that the author takes an "increasing function" $f$ to have the property $x < y\Rightarrow f(x) < f(y)$ by definition.

Comment: Hmm. The book in question is Concrete Mathematics by Graham, Knuth, Patashnik, pg 85, (3.10), Anyways, I'll check more references about the uses of increasing vs non-decreasing in the book.

Comment: Assuming that the proof relies on the choice of an arbitrary function with a property that the authors have termed "increasing," it doesn't really matter, so long as they don't take the theorem to imply anything that doesn't follow from the definition they've chosen.